# Emulators Providing Different Results

Tags: windows-phone-7, listview, data-binding, windows-phone-7-emulator, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am developing an application on windows phone with version 7.1 set as my target build. The problem i am having is that one of the listviews in on of my pages refus to display.

I have debugged to ensure the list gets parsed with contents inside of it . Also the application runs fine when i use a windows 8 emulator. But the same technique used in populating other listviews in other pages of the application work fine on all emulators aprt from this single page that does not display.

I even tried to set the colour of the binding stack panel to see if it will show up and it does but without any content.
I am really confused and my code is very perfect. I wonder if any one has seem this issue before with windows phone emulators?

```
private void countdownClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();            
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.Error.InnerException.Message + "\n Ensure You Have A Working Internet Connection");                
            return;
        }
        doc.LoadHtml(e.Result);
        String noCountdown = "<div><span>Sorry no buses are expected within 30 minutes of this stop.  Please try again later or go to www.tfl.gov.uk</span></div>";

        if (e.Result.Contains(noCountdown))
        {
            //No Buses Expected;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            HtmlNode stopCountdownNode;
            try
            {
                stopCountdownNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@id, 'stopBoard')]").SelectSingleNode("tbody");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Responce From Server");
                return;
            }

            if (stopCountdownNode != null)
            {
                HtmlNodeCollection countdownNodeList = stopCountdownNode.SelectNodes("tr");
                CountDownListBox.ItemsSource = GetCountdownList(countdownNodeList);
            } 
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<BusCountdown> GetCountdownList(HtmlNodeCollection countdownNodeList)
    {
        ObservableCollection<BusCountdown> countdownList = new ObservableCollection<BusCountdown>();
        foreach (HtmlNode countDown in countdownNodeList)
        {
            String busName = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(countDown.SelectSingleNode("*[contains(@class, 'resRoute')]").InnerHtml);
            String busDestination = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(countDown.SelectSingleNode("*[contains(@class, 'resDir')]").InnerHtml);
            String countDownTime = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(countDown.SelectSingleNode("*[contains(@class, 'resDue')]").InnerHtml);
            countdownList.Add(new BusCountdown(busName, busDestination, countDownTime));       
        }                                                    
        return countdownList;
    }

    public string GetRandomSlash()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        String slash = "";
        int rand = r.Next(1, 20);
        for (int i = 0; i < rand; i++)
        {
            slash += "/";
        }
        return slash;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your class access specifier which you use to bind to public and give it a try. Let me know if it works.

For ex:

```
public class Bindingclass
{
public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: All the binding properties are already public if not they wont even work.

Comment: properties are public by default. If not it wouldn't work anywhere... You have defined the properties in a class right? Make that class as public...\

Comment: Oh yes Max its working now. You were right all my previous classes had the public rfix apart from this one. Why? i have no clue lol. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using **Expression Blend** and also delete your previous solution file and **build a new solution**.
2. Also set the **build action** property properly for all pages.
3. Update your **SDK to 7.8** version. You will get multiple choices for Emulators - **Emulator 7.1 (256 MB), Emulator 7.1 (512 MB), Emulator 7.8 (256 MB), Emulator 7.8 (512 MB)**. Test it on all these versions and check output on each Emulator type.

I hope at least one of these helps you get things get working. Let us know.

Comment: I am using windows 8 sdk cant go any higher it works fine on all emulators only that one page does not work on win 7.1 emulator. The funny thing is the previous page on the same 7.1 emulator uses d same display technique and it works flawlessly.